# Add authorizer to api gateway in SAM json

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have this SAM:

```
"ApiGatewayApi":
  {
    "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Api",
    "Properties": {
      "StageName": "Prod",
      "Name" : "MainGateway",
      "Cors": {
        "AllowMethods": "'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE'",
        "AllowHeaders": "'access-control-allow-headers,access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,authorization,content-type'",
        "AllowOrigin": "'*'",
        "MaxAge": "'1'"
      }
    }
  },
```

I try to add an authorizer like this:

```
"RESTAuthorizerGeneral":
  {
  "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer",
  "Properties" : {
  "Name" : "HTTPAuthorizer",
  "Type" : "TOKEN",
  "IdentitySource" : "method.request.header.Authorization",
  "RestApiId" : {"Ref": "ApiGatewayApi"},
  "AuthorizerUri" : ""
    }
  },
```

1 - I get this error: ApiGatewayApi is an invalid type for this reference.

2 - How do I fill the 'AuthorizerUri' field?

Answer (score 0):

Not JSON, but there are YAML examples of how to do this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html